# Regular Expressions- Optionally Match a Word

Tags: regex

How do I make a regex that optionally matches a word in a string? For example, let's say I have a regex to match the sentence:

```
I like vanilla ice cream.
```

but I want that "vanilla" word to be optional so the same regex also matches

```
I like ice cream.
```

How do I do it? I've been using (vanilla)? but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Can you post the EXACT regex that you have been trying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only does the word `vanilla` need to be optional, but **also** the white space that follows, i.e., `(vanilla )?`:

```
String s1 = "I like vanilla icecream";
String s2 = "I like icecream";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("I like (vanilla )?icecream");
System.out.println(p.matcher(s1).matches());  // true
System.out.println(p.matcher(s2).matches());  // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
I like (vanilla )?ice cream
```

You probably forgot that extra space after "vanilla".

Answer (score 0):

Using the java [regex tester](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html):

```
I like [vanilla]? ice cream
```

Doesn't work, though ? is for 0 and 1

```
I like [vanilla]* ice cream
```

Does work

Comment: This will match 0 or more occurrences of any character that is part of "vanilla" as well as one space to either side:  "I like alinnaaaaavvva ice cream" will match, but "I like ice cream" will not.

Comment: No it doesn't... (directed at the answer, not @Michael Hays' comment.)